# Django: Uploading photo and word doc on same form not working correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an upload form that will allow a user to upload a photo, a word doc, or both. I need help with the logic so that as long they have a photo OR a document selected for uploading, the form is valid and the upload will work. It always works when I have BOTH a photo and doc, but appears to randomly work when it's just a photo or document. Here is my current code:

```
def upload(request):
"""
Uploads document/photo

"""

if request.method == 'POST':

    form1 = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    form2 = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() :
        post1 = Document(user = request.user, document= form1.cleaned_data['document'], title = form1.cleaned_data['title'])
        post1.save()
        post2 = Photo(user = request.user, alias = request.user.username, img = form2.cleaned_data['img'], title = "")
        post2.save()
        return HttpResponse(template.Template('''
                    <html><head><title>Uploaded</title></head> <body>
                    <h1>Uploaded</h1>
                    </body></html>
                    '''
                    ).render( template.Context({}))
                )

    elif form1.is_valid():
            post1 = Document(user = request.user, document = form1.cleaned_data['document'], title = form1.cleaned_data['title'])
            post1.save()

            return HttpResponse(template.Template('''
                        <html><head><title>Uploaded</title></head> <body>
                        <h1>Uploaded</h1>
                        </body></html>
                        '''
                        ).render( template.Context({}))
                    )

    else:
        if form2.is_valid():
            post2 = Photo(user = request.user, alias = request.user.username, img = form2.cleaned_data['img'], title = "")
            post2.save()
            return HttpResponse(template.Template('''
                    <html><head><title>Uploaded</title></head> <body>
                    <h1>Uploaded</h1>
                    </body></html>
                    '''
                    ).render( template.Context({}))
                )


else:  
    form1 = DocumentForm() 
    form2 = PhotoForm()
return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2':form2 }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I know there has to be a better way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Could you include the code for the forms too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to have two different forms? It seems like you may just want one form with two file fields.

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = DocumentAndPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data.get('document'):

            post1 = Document(user = request.user, document= form1.cleaned_data['document'], title = form1.cleaned_data['title'])
            post1.save()

        if form.cleaned_data.get('img'):
            post2 = Photo(user = request.user, alias = request.user.username, img = form2.cleaned_data['img'], title = "")
            post2.save()


        return HttpResponse(template.Template('''
                <html><head><title>Uploaded</title></head> <body>
                <h1>Uploaded</h1>
                </body></html>
                '''
                ).render( template.Context({}))
            )

return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form },      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Your file fields on the DocumentAndPhotoForm will need to have the [`null=True` and `blank=True`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) parameters passed in though.